# Web Client to read emails from Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, web-applications, amazon-s3, amazon-ses

I've setup Amazon SES to forward all incoming emails to an S3 bucket. Now I'd like to read them with an email client. I've seen the javascript library http://emailjs.org/ which looks promising but I'd still have to create some kind of HTML webapp. What are my options to read emails in S3 from a web browser or a standalone desktop email client? The emails are saved in raw text MIME format in S3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some great JavaScript browser examples on AWS JS SDK page: [Examples in the Browser](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-examples.html). The "Basic Usage Example" shows you how to list objects in a bucket:

```
<div id="status"></div>
<ul id="objects"></ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'myBucket'}});
  bucket.listObjects(function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Could not load objects from S3';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Loaded ' + data.Contents.length + ' items from S3';
      for (var i = 0; i < data.Contents.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById('objects').innerHTML +=
          '<li>' + data.Contents[i].Key + '</li>';
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

The main thing you need to think about here is security, unless your bucket is public you will need some sort of backend service to provide the client with a signed key to perform the operations, take a look at [getSignedUrl](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property) for this. One approach for building this service is to build a simple Lambda function that can verify authentication and provide signed keys.

Comment: Thank you! You provided great resources to get started. I was hoping for a prefab library to get up-and-running but creating one myself will be a nice exercise.

Comment: @TooSerious did you ever get around to creating that library?  I would love to use it.